# How to stop CPU fan in Linux?

Tags: hardware, cpu, fan

I use an old computer. CPU fan creates big noise. Sometimes CPU fan suddenly stops and does not work for a long time, and CPU does not get heated in these long periods, because I use very light-weight applications.

How can I stop the CPU fan indefinitely?

I use Debian Wheezy.

Comment: You don't. I'm sorry but your question is tantamount to asking us how to destroy your CPU. The fan starts/stops depending on the temperature. If it already stops sometimes, that means that temperature control is working. Making it stop when it doesn't want to is a Very Bad Idea®.

Comment: The periods I am referring are weeks, or more. I use the same applications those times. And when it starts to work, it does not stop, even when no application is working, and the huge noise also accompanies with it. I am able to detect when it works and when it stops solely by the noise, by the way. It is not related to it, in my opinion.

Comment: I'm sure that's a more compelling reason why not do it. Just dust off your system. BTW, CPU fans doesn't "stop" even when they are not being used, they just spin down so you can't hear them.

Comment: Braiam, it really stops sometimes. And when it stops it takes weeks until it starts to spin again. I can prove it by showing CPU fan results, now saw some codes for it. BY the way, why did you removed /cpu and /hardware tags? I saw very similar subjects having these, so I exactly copied.

Comment: They were mistagged if that's the case. Check the /hardware excerpt for more information. BTW, CPU fans are not different from other fans.

Comment: Perhaps my problem is something else, I think some people may be connecting my computer - I am into politics. Perhaps I can write this problem in security part of the website then. I think what you wrote here did not help the situation, BY the way.. Anyways, thanks..

Answer (score 5):

There is probably no way to stop the CPU fan from software, especially if you use an old computer. If you really want to stop the fan, you should probably just open the computer and detach the cable connecting the fan to the motherboard. At next reboot your BIOS *may* complain that the fan is not working (it does so in order to protect the CPU from overheating), but in this case you can probably disable the check.

Of course, as other have already said, this expose your CPU to permanent damage. I do not know how much old is your computer, but probably the last consumer CPUs that could be safely used with just a passive heat sink were Intel Pentium, maybe Pentium 2, and AMDs of the same epoch, which is now *really* old. If you really want to run your CPU without fan, I suggest you to check that the heat sink is clean (without dust on it) and the thermal conducting paste is properly applied between the CPU and the heat sink.

Even more, though, I suggest you to just buy another fan. They are really cheap and silent nowadays.

Comment: I had to down-vote it, it's an advice for an alternative solution of the core problem. BUT, it doesn't answer the asked question. And, such advises should be comments.

Comment: @kravemir Yes, it does. The question was "How can I stop then fan?" and the answer was "You cannot do it from software, here is how you can do it modifying hardware".

Answer (score 3):

If the CPU fan (or any other fan) is very loud, and even stops over periods of time, that means the oil inside has run dry, or possibly the bearing is already damaged.

Try [lubricating](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/quiet-noisy-computer-fans-with-a-drop-of-oil/) it, or replace it with a new fan.

Under no circumstances attempt to stop the fan completely, even if you are only running "lightweight applications". This will destroy your CPU sooner or later.